# Mobile Website Anchor Links Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am having issues with my anchor links on certain pages of my mobile website (the index page works fine), and I have made changes that work temporarily (changing the 'http: // example.com', to 'http: // www.example.com' ), but within 30 minutes the links are not working again.  I have spoken to the very (un)useful Godaddy, who cannot seem to help me as they dont deal with 'coding' issues....  any help would be appreciated in this matter.  The url: http://www.removalcompare.com/mobile/site/test/index.html (the navigation is on the footer, and index works, but most of the other pages do not).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a working fix](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/removalcompare/mobile/site/test/index.html)

[You can download the edited files here](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/removalcompare.zip)

**Problem 1**

I see that you have used WinHTTrack to copy a website. Unfortunately, the software has made a bit of a mess with the site's links. If you look at your console you we see several errors that are showing.

Specifically, WinHTTrack converted all of the schema-less urls (`//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js`) to relative urls (`../../code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js`) which you will need to correct

I would just make them `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js`

---

Fix all that, and you will start seeing the error message "Page load error" when you click on any link. So, we're not done yet.

Let's look at [how links work in jQuery Moblie](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/links/):

> To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via AJAX. To do this unobtrusively, the framework parses the link's href to formulate an AJAX request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner. All this is done automatically by jQuery Mobile.
>
> If the AJAX request is successful, the new page content is added to the DOM, all mobile widgets are auto-initialized, then the new page is animated into view with a page transition.
>
> If the AJAX request fails, the framework will display a small error message overlay (styled in the "e" swatch) that disappears after a brief time so this doesn't break the navigation flow. View an example of the error message.

---

**Problem 2**

Additionally, WinHTTrack was unable to find the file `js/calc.js` on the server you copied the site from. By default, when this happens WinHTTrack makes an html page as sort of a placeholder for the missing file and links to it instead

So, in this case WinHTTrack made `<script src="js/calc.js"></script>` into `<script src="js/calc.html"></script>` which is also causing problems.

Looking back at [how links work in jQuery Moblie](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/links/):

> Note: You cannot link to a multipage document with AJAX navigation active because the framework will only load the first page it finds, not the full set of internal pages. In these cases, you must link without AJAX (see next section) for a full page refresh to prevent potential hash collisions. There is currently a subpage plugin that makes it possible to load in multi-page documents.

My guess is that the inclusion of `<script src="js/calc.html"></script>` makes the pages all "multipage documents" which is causing the ajax requests to fail when you click any of the links. I could be wrong about the specifics of why this happens, nevertheless, fixing this makes your links work.

**To fix this problem:**

- If you need `js/calc.js`, find a copy of it and add it to your folder then change all the links to `<script src="js/calc.js"></script>`
- If you dont need `js/calc.js` just delete all of the `<script src="js/calc.html"></script>` link in all of the files

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution, by adding in an onclick event:          onClick="document.location.href='site.com'"

Posted again just incase you fall into this predicament :)

Comment: This doesn't address the issues in your files at all.